# Is it possible to return array from a driver function?

Tags: python, image, drivers

I'm trying to write a driver function, which creates histogram image from image texture node, or basically an array of numbers of pixels, which correspond to tones(values in HSV) from 0 to 1 (or from 0 to 255 with step 1).
I did it, but if I return generated array from my driver function, I get the error:
TypeError: must be real number, not list.
It looks like I can't do return an array from driver functions. But I'm not sure.
What do you guys think about it? Is this true?
If so, I'll appreciate any advice how to pass generated array from a driver function to Blender material nodes.

Below is my non working code.

```
from random import random
from math import isclose
import numpy as np
import colorsys

gl = []
pixelNums = [0] * 256

def foo(self, name="Image Texture", index=0, default=0.0):
    global gl
    global pixelNums
    #print(self, self.id_data)
    node_tree = self.id_data
    tn = node_tree.nodes.get(name)
    if tn:
        print(tn)
        if tn.image:
            if not gl:
                pxs_slow = pixels = tn.image.pixels
                #recast, faster
                pxs = list(pxs_slow)
                num_pixels = len(pxs)
                
                #gl = [pxs[i:i+4] for i in range(num_pixels)[::4]]
                gl = [colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(pxs[i],pxs[i+1], pxs[i+2]) for i in range(num_pixels)[::4]]
                
            #gradations of grey
            #256
            for i in range(0, 256, 1):
                val = i/255
                for pixel in gl:
                    if isclose(pixel[2], val, rel_tol=0.015):
                        pixelNums[i] += 1

            return pixelNums
    
    
    return pixelNums

bpy.app.driver_namespace["foo"] = foo
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are returning an array from your function, that's why it's saying `TypeError: must be number not list`. What is the code you are feeding it into that is rejecting the input?

Comment: I add this driver code to any node in my material, for instance in Input->Value node just like #foo(self) and tick self option on.
I know that this error happens because I return array. My question is - is it possible to return arrays from a driver function at all? If it's not, I need any solution how to return array to material node to display histogram image of an image texture.

Comment: You can use arrays within a driver but see [Driver Expressions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#expressions) and related manual sections.  You cannot return an array.  Drivers return single floating point values.

Comment: As has been mentioned, a driver should only return a single float. It's probably not great for performance to run a heavy function like this in a driver. What you could try instead is to create a depsgraph handler which checks if the image has changed and then updates the histogram. https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre

Comment: Is it blender addon API? For such a simple task it's too much to create an addon as for me. What I think about is in driver function create another output image, fill it with histogram array and set this image into another Image Texture node in material. This way I'll get output array in my material. The driver function is really heavy. Probably it could be optimized. In photoshop histogram image in levels shows very quickly.